# ExpectNew is not being called twice for same class

Tags: java, mocking, powermock, easymock

I was writing junit test using EasyMock .So for a object :-

```
DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(Data data , Provider provider);
```

So i had to mock behaviour twice , like this :-

> ```
> @Mock
> DataProvider dataProvider1 , dataProvider2;
> ```

```
   1. PowerMock.expectNew(DataProvider.class, dataRequest, provider1).thenReturn(mockDataProvider1);
   2. PowerMock.replay(DataProvider.class);
   3. PowerMock.expectNew(DataProvider.class, dataRequest, provider2).thneReturn(mockDataProvider2);
   4. PowerMock.replay(DataProvider.class);
```

But when i'm trying to execute this . this is throwing error at line number 2 .
When i removed line 3 and 4 , it got succeeded without any problem.

and i need to use it twice in my behaviour . Can somebody please help ?

Comment: Can you give a full test case. With the @Prepare and the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replay() method shouldn't be called twice for same class in same test method.

so :-

```
   1. PowerMock.expectNew(DataProvider.class, dataRequest, provider1).thenReturn(mockDataProvider1);
   3. PowerMock.expectNew(DataProvider.class, dataRequest, provider2).thneReturn(mockDataProvider2);
   4. PowerMock.replay(DataProvider.class);
```

This thing worked .

Same suggestion for mockStatic() function as well.

One should also remember to use mockStatic() function only once for a class in one test method.
so :-

```
PowerMock.mockStatic(DataProvider.class);
```

This should be used only once in a test-method.